# Hotkey control keycodes confusion

Tags: c++, winapi

`HKM_GETHOTEKY` returns virtual key code and modifiers but they're not the same as the ordinary virtual key codes? What is the purpose of `HOTKEYF_EXT` and how do i use it?

If i press F5 the hotkey control returns `0x74` which is `VK_F5`, but when i press the right arrow key, it returns `0x27` which is `VK_RIGHT` and the HOTKEYF_EXT bit is set on the modifier. If i use `HKM_SETHOTKEY` with `VK_RIGHT` as virtual key and no modifiers, it shows `"Num 6"`

I find this very strange and I need to be able to pass any virtual keys to the hotkey control window, and therefore i need to understand this `HOTKEYF_EXT` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

"Extended keys" are keys that were added to the original IBM PC keyboard layout.  Which looked like this:

[image]

Note how it didn't yet have dedicated cursor keys, they were integrated with the keypad at the right.  And note how the right-arrow matches Numpad-6.  The dedicated right-arrow key added to later keyboard layouts (the Enhanced layout with 101 keys) is distinguished by the HOTKEYF_EXT bit.

Comment: Can i somehow convert the HKM_GETHOTKEY return value to ordinary virtual key code?

Comment: You are already getting it, it is the low byte of the return value.  Just use retval & 0xff.

Comment: Thanks but sorry, I meant; how can I give the hot key control `VK_RIGHT` correctly? If i only give `VK_RIGHT` without `HOTKEYF_EXT` it shows up as "Num 6". When am i supposed to use `HOTKEYF_EXT`?

Comment: You are supposed to use the data you get from HKM_GETHOTKEY for your WM_SETHOTKEY message.  It is unclear to me why you have a problem doing this.

Comment: I want to use the hotkey control for use with the RegisterHotkey function!